# How does .NET dependency injection resolve between generic and specific matches?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

In .NET 6 you can map a generic interface to a generic implementation like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));
```

But say you want to configure `IService<Foo>` to return `FooService` instead of the generic `Service<Foo>`.

If you add this line it seems to work, favoring the specific type match over the generic regardless of the order they are defined in:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<Foo>, FooService>();
```

Is this behaviour that can be depended upon, and the correct way to do this? Am I even trying to solve the right problem?

The source for the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/3ae87395f638a533f37b8e3385f6d3f199a72f4f/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src) for reference.

Comment: Yes, this behavior can be depended on. This behavior is specified in MS.DI's tests and adapter tests. Container adapter implementations need to mimic this behavior to be compliant to the Conforming Container DI abstraction.